# How I can find which sequence is associated with a Primary Key of Serial type?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
create table my table (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,value TEXT);
```

And I try to find the sequence that serial creates:

```
SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name 
FROM information_schema.sequences 
ORDER BY sequence_name ;
```

How I can associate a listed serial with `table.id` Primary Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try "information_schema.columns" table

```
SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_default ilike '%nextval%';
```